# What software is best at ripping multi-CD audiobooks?

Tags: mp3, audiobook

I want to take a 6 CD audiobook and rip it into MP3s that I can listen to on my phone.  Maybe this works ok if the audiobook has already been entered into some CDDB.  But my CDs aren't recognized.

When I try to import them into iTunes, they all have Track 1-xx.  And even though I set the Disc x of y value in the CD Info, iTunes seems to get confused and thinks each disc imported duplicate files.

Windows Media Player is painfully out of date these days and I even had trouble editing the menus on my Windows 10 machine.

There must be software out there that is good at this.  But all the Google articles I find online are outdated and don't seem to work for multi-CD audiobooks.

I can't be the only one with this problem, right?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because.

Comment: This is off topic here. If you want to find out, go to ripping sites.

Answer (score 2):

I used portable 'MarkAble' + installed legacy ver. 12 iTunes, with the optical drive added to 'device' list in VBox, on WinXP-Pro.
  MarkAble won't work past iTunes v12, and has been discontinued. I used a portable version of MarkAble. It's been quite some time.
  My GF got an iPod Nano for Christmas, and it was my job to manage it. iTunes is like an infection, so I installed it on a VM.
Sharepod (3.9.9-free)-portable is the best iPod management software.
  With a fast computer, you can rip 20 or so CD's fairly quickly, and far better quality than 'Audible'.
  There are probably other ways to do this, but this method preserves the book parts as 'audiobook' for Apple hardware.
  It's annoying enough you must use iTunes to update iPod's firmware. Don't let it tamper with your audiobook or music collections. It will wreak havoc with anything not purchased from Apple.
  MarkAble also allows including book covers on your rips.